# Egress data google cloud platform tracking

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have recently started using Google Cloud Platform. I am looking into making a vpn service with it. I have created an obfuscated OpenVPN server with it running on port 443. The only problem I have with that is the egress data usage. I have given it to a friend to test for now as I am operating on the free credit. I am wondering if there is a way to track data usage to a specific ip so I know that it is not somebody other than the two of us. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the two peers authenticate themselves properly, then there is no risk of being hacked in a way. Note that there are some requirements from Google side, to establish VPN tunnel, that need to be met.

You still can check that information in your Console, under Logging, selecting Cloud VPN Gateway.

Comment: Now it is showing 64 gigabites of egress data usage. I don't think I have used that much egress data. How do I find the source of the data usage?

Comment: where do you see it?

Comment: I see it in the transactions section and I am being charged, but my goal for this is a small VPN that I can use that stays under the always free compute engine limits, buy I don't know where the 64gb of egress data usage is coming feom